# Processing string of 3D variables in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, variables

I have been trying to write a script to process a string of 3D variables, `eV50`, `eV60`, `eV70`, etc. (meaning extracted value from the `1950`, `1960`, `1970` and so on. These 3D variables have the size of 31x145x192.) into a string of 3D output, that is, `m1`, `m2`, `m3`, etc. (dimension of 1x145x192).

This might be pretty straightforward to some of you, but I have been pulling my hair out in the last 24 hours trying to get this working. I tried these two approaches by using loops and EVAL, but I have troubles understanding the '' bracket in the expression, so I guess this is why I couldn't balance the equation correctly.

*X is the data set `eV50`, `eV60`, `eV70`, etc. (meaning extracted value from the `1950`, `1960`, `1970`, etc.)

Basically I'm trying to turn this script into a loop or some sort of similar:

'[          m1         v1         ]          =          extfunc    (          eV50       )          ;
[          m2         v2         ]          =          extfunc    (          eV60       )          ;
[          m3         v3         ]          =          extfunc    (          eV70       )          ;
[          m4         v4         ]          =          extfunc    (          eV80       )          ;
[          m5         v5         ]          =          extfunc    (          eV90       )          ;
[          m6         v6         ]          =          extfunc    (          eV100      )          ;
and so on...
'

---

Approach 1:

> '[mean vars] = eval(['extfunc( sprintf(',eV%d', (50:10:80)') ')']); '

---

Approach 2:

*I have renamed `eV50`, `eV60`, `eV70` into `eV1`, `eV2`, `eV3` and so on...

> ' for i=1:6
>
> m(i)=extfunc_h(sprintf('eV%d', i));
>
> end '

Usage of extfunc :-

```
[mean variance] = extfunc(eV50)
```

In approach 1, I've unbalanced equations and approach 2, MATLAB returned the error message

> ??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.'

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem with approach 1 is that each ' starts or ends a string, but you want some of them to be part of the string that is supposed to be produced. You need two ' for this:

```
[mean vars] = eval(['extfunc( sprintf('',eV%d'', (50:10:80)'') '')']);
```

This will still not do what you want. If you want a string to be produced for each element of `50:10:80`, you will need a loop.

The problem with the second approach is probably that your `extfunc` returns a vector/array/matrix (for `mean`; note that you do not record `variance` this way), but your assigment `m(i)= ...` can take only scalar values. If `mean` is a vector, try `m(i,:)=...`.

However, I would rather question your general approach of dealing with strings and `eval` here. If it is so easy to rename the variables, why not put them into a cell array or (n+1)-dimensional matrix and have your functions work on actual variable content instead of variable name strings?

[edit: misleading "of" -> "or" before "(n+1)-dimensional matrix"]

**Edit in response to edited question:**
Although the purpose of SO is not to let other people do your work, what you want seems to be quite straightforward:

```
year = 50:10:100;
for i=1:length(year)
    cmdstr = ['[m' int2str(i) ' v' int2str(i) '] = extfunc(eV' int2str(year(i)) ');'];
    eval(cmdstr);
end
```

If you prefer `sprintf` to char array concatenations for some reason, try

```
cmdstr = sprintf('[m%d v%d]=extfunc(eV%d);',i,i,year(i))
```

instead. I remain unconvinced that using `eval` and different variable names is a more elegant solution to your problem than collecting `eV50`, `eV60`, etc. in one matrix, e.g. `eV(:,:,:,1) = eV50; eV(:,:,:,2) = eV60;` etc. or a cell array and working on that one, unless your original data source is indeed a MATLAB binary file with variables named thusly.

Comment: The data source were a structure contained a variable with 56940x145x192, even I am working on a relatively powerful UNIX version of Matlab (think it has a 8TB memory), it failed to load.  On the other hand, I am interested in decal temporal scale, so I can organise the data in decal period.  These variable then get process various function such as statistical analysis fitting and extractions.  With your help, I can easily change the function and variable, then do them as batch processes.  Thank you arne.b!  This is great help and I have a much better understandinf of the EVAL and SPRINTF now.

Answer (score 1):

It is not quite clear what should be the input to `extfunc` (what is `X`) - is it a single variable, i.e `ev50`, or a list of variables?

Anyway, the problem in the 1st approach is that the `sprintf` produces the following string:

```
,eV50,eV60,eV70,eV80
```

so you have an extra `,` at the begging. In addition, it fits only if `extfunc` gets a list of variables as an input. Otherwise, you should reformat your string.